# Matplotlib colormap mapping with stable value

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapping, geopandas, colormap

thanks for help.

Here is the question:

I have some values of earthquake Intensity(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7 total 9 levels), And I also have 9 colors for colormap.

```
    color_map = [
        '#f3f3f3',
        '#1aff1a',
        '#ffff00',
        '#ff8900',
        '#ff5500',
        '#b64100',
        '#993300',
        '#aa3c00',
        '#800080'
]
cm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(color_map)

draw_area.plot("Intensity", ax=axes, cmap=cm, legend=True) #it suppose to be mapped by "Intensity" values
```

and two cases happened

Situation1:
If I got many "different" values of "Intensity" such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,6.5,7 than my map came out with many colors like this.
[image: Situation1]

Situation2:
If I got many "Same" values of "Intensity" such as 4,4,4,4,4 or 5,5,5,5,5 than my map will not map the colormap, it came out with same color.(all areas mapped by the first color #f3f3f3)
[image: Situation2]

I want to map the color "one value to one color", how to solve this?(if i got 2,2,2,2, these areas suppose to be mapped by #1aff1a)

Thanks for help!

Comment: I mean i need to use absolute value to map the colormap.

Comment: To have a consistent mapping between values and colors, you could use `plot(..., cmap=cm, vmin=1, vmax=9)`

Comment: You may also want a BoundaryNorm if all you want are those 9 colours.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the method to this situation, I need to use absolute value to map the colors.

So I fix the code, and it works!

here is the code:

```
cmap, norm = matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors(cLevel, color_map, extend="max")
```

Using from_levels_and_colors to get absolute mapping.